# Area of a smiling mouth

Tags: calculus, integration

> Having the two functions $$f(x) = x^2 + \sqrt{16-x^2}$$ and $$g(x) = x^2 - \sqrt{16-x^2}$$
>
> plotted as
>
> [image]
>
> how to find out the area of the enclosed area which looks like a "mouth" in an **elegant way**?

### My thoughts

I've thought about adding $16$ to both functions, which should have no effect on the integrals of the two functions, but *is this the most elegant way?*

I've come up with 16 by observing that the lower curve only touches the $x$ axis, anything else (like 15 or 17) makes it cut the $x$ axis, which complicates things.

But *why is $16$ the right number?*

With $+16$, the two functions look like this:

[image]

*If $+16$ is the most elegant technique, how to proceed afterwards?*

Comment: I think this may be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @DavidMitra Yeah I realise that. `I've come up with 16 by observing that the lower curve only touches the x axis, anything else (like 15 or 17) makes it cut the x axis, which complicates things.

But why is 16 the right number?` - Why is 16 the right number?

Comment: $g(x)=x^2$ touches the $x$-axis even without any translation, doesn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, but the question is to find the area in an elegant way.

Comment: The plots do not match your function expressions. So how should we know what the significance of 16 should be? Moreover, your second plot is only translated up by $4$ for the red line, not $16$, and then things are somehow scaled!?

Comment: Shouldn't you add $4$? You essentially want to shift up, and $g(0)=-4$. (By the way, the inequality sign in your definition of $g$ is a typo, correct?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the difference $f(x)-g(x)$ and integrate between intersectiopn points (i.e. zeroes of the difference), so there is no need to translate the two functions beforehand.

Then the most elegant way (assuming $g(x)$ should rather be $x^2-\sqrt{16-x^2}$) is to observe that the term $x^2$ can be subtracted from both $f$ and $g$ and that the area is then simply a circular disc with radius $4$.